# The difference between objective-c @ "hello" and "hello"?

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa

What is difference in Objective-C between `@"hello"` and `"hello"`?

Comment: If you don't even know a fundamental thing like this, please do learn C properly before diving deep into Cocoa/Objective-C, else you'll get lost and shoot yourself and your users in the foot.

Comment: Why this nasty comment to a simple yet clear question? Kevin might be just looking for a good answer.

Answer (score 7):

```
@"hello"
```

creates an instance of the `NSString` class (it's a proper Objective-C object), whereas

```
"hello"
```

will create a simple C string (of type `const char[]`).

Comment: Actually, depending on which version of `clang` / `gcc` you are using, (in this case, the versions before objc literals were added), `@"str"` literals returned read only strings that resided entirely in static data, and no string was "created". Just a little technical detail. Now, whether or not a literal Is a static reference or not is implementation defined.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that @"hello" is simply a shortcut for `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"hello"];`  I think that it helps show the real difference....  +1 though.

Comment: @inafziger that isnt always the case, If you read my above comment. While semantically they may **seem** the same, implementation-wise they're actually quite different.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Well, they are functionally equivalent and I think that it helps to demonstrate what behavior to expect from the created object.  Implementation details are just that:  implementation details.

Comment: @lnafziger but it's not true. Implementation details are not a toy, especially in the case of an absolute beginner.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Right. By 'creation', I meant either runtime or compile-time realization of an instance (regardless to the memory management details).

Comment: Implementation details are subject to change so should not be relied upon. They are purposefully abstracted (which I was trying ro do here as well). I get your point, and agree, however in this case I think that fine points like this are likely to not be understood, and aren't even important (in this context).  At any rate, thanks for pointing out the difference for those who miggt find it useful.

Comment: And, I just realized that you were referring to old versions where the actual functionality is different so my entire point is moot.  Nevermind, my comment only appliws to string literals.

Comment: And one thing for a beginner (although you all will definitely shoot me) : `NSString *str=@"Hello";` is correct while `NSString *str="Hello";` is incorrect and cause a compile time error... lol

Answer (score 0):

@"hello" is NSString(objective c class) constant and "hello" string constant